# How to add docs to post body model on fast api view?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

For example imagine that we have two endpoints:

```py
class FooRequest(BaseModel):
    data: str


@router.post("/foo/", response_model=FooRequest)
async def foo_view(data: FooRequest) -> FooRequest:
    ...


@router.get("/bar/", response_model=FooRequest)
async def bar_view(data: str = Query(..., description="Data param")) -> FooRequest:
    ...
```

In swagger UI `/bar/` endpoint will have properly documented query param and `/foo/` will have some abstract example of post body without any description.

So how can I document post body model?

Comment: Have you looked into the swagger documentation already? https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/
And in the FastAPI docs:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare an example for a Pydantic model using `Config` and `schema_extra`.

```
class FooRequest(BaseModel):
    data: str

    class Config:
        schema_extra = {
            "FooRequest": {
                "name": "Foo Request",
                "description": "Data param",
            }
        }
```

---

Also with `Field` you declare extra info for your JSON Schema.

```
from pydantic import Field

...

class FooRequest(BaseModel):
    data: str = Field(..., example="Data param for Foo Request")
    description: Optional[str] = Field(None, example="Description for Foo")
```

---

The same way you can pass extra info to `Field`, you can do the same with `Path`, `Query`, `Body`, etc.

For example, you can pass an example for a body request to `Body`:

```
from fastapi import Body

...

class FooRequest(BaseModel):
    data: str


@router.post("/foo/", response_model=FooRequest)
async def foo_view(data: FooRequest = Body(
            ...,
            example={
                "name": "Foo Request",
                "description": "data param",
            },
        ),
    ) -> FooRequest:
```

Comment: `Field(..., description="foo", example="bar")` is exactly what I needed, tnx